# How can I set elements' transformation point in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3

I want set an element's transformation point which is put on the stage.But I can't find the property in DisplayObject. Where is it ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define a transformation matrix for the displayObject. The transformation point is a property of the matrix, which can be set using transformPoint().

[See AS3 documentation for matrix.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix.html)

Answer (score 0):

Place your MovieClip on the scene, and select transformation tool (hotkey `Q`), you will see black squares for scaling object, and you will see white square. White square is a pivot for transformation, simply move it in any directions.

Comment: There is no code that you are looking for... You use transformation point when you do transformation (scale, rotate, skew). And it can be done by the help of `Matrix` and applying new matrix to the display object: `myObject.transform.matrix = newMatrix;`

Comment: Cunningham's Law: "The best way to get the right answer on the Internet is not to ask a question, it's to post the wrong answer."